# How close would a planet need to be to its star to be dangerous but still habitable with thriving civilisations?

Tags: science-based, planets, space, aliens

I'm creating an alien species and want to have them a bit too close to their star but of course, don't want to kill them. They're not very advanced technology wise but they have powers caused by radiation from a war.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, megasaurus. I feel compelled to point out that distance from a star is only one of the many variables that factor in to the habitability of a planet and therefore you may need to be more specific about what you're asking. What exactly do you mean by 'dangerous'? Should your species be worried about solar flares? Solar Winds? Or are you looking for a planet that's just plain hot? Are you talking about a massive, really hot star or a red giant or something else completely? Sustaining life is a delicate balance of many factors so some clarification would be helpful.

Comment: Greetings and welcome!  Please take a moment to review the [help] and [tour] so you can get a better idea what kinds of questions we fields here.  Right now, your question really too broad to be answerable. You've got what what looks to be an interesting world, but we deal in focused questions that pinpoint one particular problem or issue in worldbuilding. I'm going to vote to put your question on hold while you edit it.

Comment: @elemtilas I'm not really sure what to add to the question to make it more 'specific' so I might just leave it as is, considering I got my answer- but thanks for telling me. I'll try to include more information next time.

Comment: Another issue is accepting the first answer to come along within the first few days after asking your question. That's poor practice is it tends to put people off of trying to give you a better answer.  Really, you're not off to a good start!  With your next question, I'd recommend taking it to the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/639/how-does-the-sandbox-work-how-do-i-use-it) for a trial run.

Comment: @elemtilas I was satisfied with the answer so I accepted it. The question is on hold anyway so I don't see why not. I appreciate the concern about my apparent bad start, but... I'm fine, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when we are talking about planets in the habitable zone, we speak of planets that could have liquid water on the surface (since that is considered a prerequisite for non-exotic life). Too close, and the water will boil away; too far, and the water will freeze. A planet on the inner edge of the habitable zone might have boiling surface water at the equator and hence lots of cloud and hot rain, something that a species should have no problem adapting to. If the planet is in a very elliptic orbit, the water might only be boiling during the closest approach, but in larger regions, making for a dangerous summer season.

Also worth considering: A planet very close to its sun is likely to be tidally locked, always facing the same side to the sun, meaning that the sunward side is blisteringly hot, while the opposite side might be frozen. Only a roughly ring-shaped twillight zone will be habitable, and the weather could be very extreme.

The planet might also be orbiting an [intrinsic variable star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_star#Intrinsic_variable_stars), with massive flares at regular intervals. Life during a flare would be quite dangerous, and it is possible that any species living on such a planet would enter some kind of hibernation state, possibly underground, during such a flare.

On a different note: What kind of 'powers' caused by radiation do you imagine your species has? Outside of superhero comics, the only power you could feasibly get from radiation exposure is improved resistance to radiation. Radiation also causes mutation, and while most mutations by far are detrimental, there may be a few advantageous ones. Your species may thus exhibit great variation in (non-exotic) abilities, but the downside would be a lot more disabled people - unless we are talking so far after the radiation event that any detrimental mutations will have died out (possibly through [eugenics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugenics)) .

Comment: Because this story is sort of a fantasy scifi, it's powers on the 'magic' side, but the species doesn't call it magic (or whatever their word for it would be), because they've had it their whole lives.
Thanks for the answer!